# Replacing text with a checkbox using ReplaceWith

Tags: jquery, replacewith

I'm having trouble replacing text with a div that includes a checkbox.  When I have the following code, the text successfully gets replaced:

```
<p>Hello</p
<p class="replaced">Hello</p>
<p class="replaced">World</p>

<script>
$( ".replaced" ).replaceWith("<div>REPLACING TEXT.</div>");

</script>
```

When the replacing text includes a checkbox, however, the script stops working. To be specific, the following does not work:

```
<p>Hello</p
<p class="replaced">Hello</p>
<p class="replaced">World</p>

<script>
$( ".replaced" ).replaceWith("<div><input type="checkbox" id="fractionsandratioscheck1" class="checkappear"/>REPLACING TEXT.</div>");

</script>
```

If someone could explain how to fix this, I would appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

your problem is that you're using html `"` inside your javascript `"`

you must use alternating quotes inside this string

```
$( ".replaced" ).replaceWith("<div><input type="checkbox" id="fractionsandratioscheck1" class="checkappear"/>REPLACING TEXT.</div>");
```

it should look something like this

```
$( ".replaced" ).replaceWith('<div><input type="checkbox" id="fractionsandratioscheck1" class="checkappear"/>REPLACING TEXT.</div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$( ".replaced" ).replaceWith("<div><input type='checkbox' id='fractionsandratioscheck1' class='checkappear'/>REPLACING TEXT.</div>");//escape string properly
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Hello</p
<p class="replaced">Hello</p>
<p class="replaced">World</p>
```

Only problem with OP is the `""` change them to `''`